# Load form results in Bootstrap modal with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show the results of the form page in a Bootstrap modal.

Everything is working, but not the replacement of the modal body content with the data from form page.
Where I'm doing the wrong turn? When I show the results in an alert, its working fine...

```js
// this is the id of the form
$("#idform").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

    var form = $(this);
    var url = "form.html"; //form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               //alert(data); // show response from the php script. -> Working fine   

               // Here is (i guess) the problem zone...:
               $("#modal-confirmation").modal('show').on("show", function(e) {
                    $(this).find(".modal-body").load(data);     
               });                                           
           }
         });


});
```

Comment: The event is "show.bs.modal" not "show": https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use load method because you already used ajax and get the data so use it directly when you need...

```js
// this is the id of the form
$("#idform").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

    var form = $(this);
    var url = "form.html"; //form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               //alert(data); // show response from the php script. -> Working fine   

               // Here is (i guess) the problem zone...:
               $("#modal-confirmation").modal('show');
               $("#modal-confirmation .modal-body").html(data);
                                                   
           }
         });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$("#modal-confirmation .modal-body").html(data);
$("#modal-confirmation").modal('show');
```