# Bootstrap modal doesn't show database search results

Tags: javascript, php

I've implemented [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55041331/load-form-results-in-bootstrap-modal-with-ajax) code into my website. This code helps me to get the search results on the same page, in a Bootstrap modal, without accessing another page in the browser.

Everything works: the modal appears, close, besides the PHP code that I have in search.php. I run console.log to see what data I get from search.php and I get only the HTML code, the PHP code is excluded. I am thinking that, maybe, I wrote the code wrong or maybe the brackets are not good positioned, but I've tried any solution that came into my mind.

**index.php**

```
$("#searchForm").submit(function(e) {
// Avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
e.preventDefault();

var searchForm = $(this);
var searchData = searchForm.serialize(); // Serialize the form's elements.
var searchURL = "map/search.php";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: searchURL,
    cache: false,
    data: searchData,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#searchModal .modal-content").html(data);
        $("#searchModal").modal('show');
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
    });
});
```

**console.log / alert()**:

```
<!-- search_modal_content -->
<div class = "modal-content">
    <div class = "modal-header">
        <h4 class = "modal-title">Rezultate cautare</h4>
    </div>

    <div class = "modal-body">
            <div class = "modal-footer">
        <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-danger" data-dismiss = "modal">Inchide</button>
    </div>
</div>


<script type = "text/javascript">
    $('.close, .btn-danger').click(function() {
        $("#searchModal" ).modal('hide');
    });
</script>
```

**search.php**

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    require_once __DIR__ . '../../config/config.inc.php';

?>

<!-- search_modal_content -->
<div class = "modal-content">
    <div class = "modal-header">
        <h4 class = "modal-title">Rezultate cautare</h4>
    </div>

    <div class = "modal-body">
        <?php 
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $searchValue = $_POST['search'];
        
                $search_result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM clubajj WHERE Nume or ADRESA LIKE '%$searchValue%'");
                $count = mysqli_num_rows($search_result);

                if($count < 1) {
                    echo '<p class = "text-align-center font-weight-bold">Nu s-a gasit niciun rezultat care sa corespunda cu cautarea dumneavoastra.</p>';
                } else { 
        ?>
        <table class = "table table-responsive table-inverse table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Nume</th>
                    <th>Judet</th>
                    <th>Adresa</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_result)) {
                ?>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Nume']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Judet']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Adresa']; ?></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php } mysqli_close($link); ?>
    <div class = "modal-footer">
        <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-danger" data-dismiss = "modal">Inchide</button>
    </div>
</div>


<script type = "text/javascript">
    $('.close, .btn-danger').click(function() {
        $("#searchModal" ).modal('hide');
    });
```

```
<form class = "d-flex" id = "searchForm" method = "POST">
                        <input class = "form-control me-2" type = "text" placeholder = "Cautare" aria-label = "Cautare" name = "search">
                        <button class = "btn btn-outline-success" type = "submit" name = "submit" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#searchModal">Cauta</button>
                    </form>
```

Comment: The most likely reason for this would be that `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {` returned false, and therefore the rest of the content within that block was not output. Unfortunately you didn't show us what your form looks like, or what the content of `searchData` is, so we can't say for sure if that's happening. Have you attempted to debug it yourself at all?

Comment: P.S. It's not merely the PHP-generated content which is excluded - if you notice, the hard-coded table header part is missing too - this is another clue that it's simply not entering that `if` block.

Comment: I've added the form, as you said, @ADyson.

Comment: Thanks. It could be because your `submit` button doesn't have a `value`, therefore no value is probably set on the server for that when the data is received. You can verify what's sent by looking at your browser's network tool for the AJAX request and look at the form data sent (that's the kind of thing I meant in my original comment where I asked if you'd done any debugging).

Comment: @ADyson, I've looked where you told me and this is what I got: https://i.imgur.com/KLxaCjN.png. I've been using AJAX request on another page aswell, and this is the data that I get from that page: https://i.imgur.com/CXfsKIj.png. On the old version for this search form (when the search_results are shown on separate page), the `submit` button didn't have any value and works perfectly.

Comment: Those pictures are looking at a preview of the _response_ coming back from the server. I'm asking you to look at what is _sent_ - i.e. the contents of the request going to the server. If you go to the "headers" tab next to it, and scroll right to the bottom you should see a form data section where it shows you what was sent. Then you can establish if the "submit" parameter was sent and whether or not it contained a value, and whether the search parameter was sent correctly as well.

Comment: If it is submitted correctly, then you should move onto to doing some [server-side debugging](http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/basic-debugging/) of the PHP code

Comment: Solved it! The problem was that the `if(isset($_POST['submit'])` was missing an `!`.

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want? If you write `if(!isset($_POST['submit'])` then it will only run the query and output the table when "submit" is **not** set. Are you sure that isn't just a workaround for that value not being set? Did you check the form data in the AJAX request as I mentioned? I appreciate it worked previously when you weren't using AJAX, but it's possible that jQuery's serialize() does something different with the form data. You need to find and fix the issue, not alter the server-side functionality to do something unintuitive.

Comment: In fact, I've just checked and https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ says specfically: _"No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button"_ . So I suggest moving your "submit" value to a hidden field then it'll be serialised properly. Changing the PHP code as you've mentioned just means it would end up erroring if it was called without a proper form submission having taken place.

Answer (score -1):

YOu need to move all html code in search.php to index.php. Your search controller response json data only. in below js request, render json to html when got response data from search result.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: searchURL,
    cache: false,
    data: searchData,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#searchModal .modal-content .table tbody").html("");
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
           //insert each table row here:  
           //$("#searchModal .modal-content .table tbody").append(".....");
           //your data row is: data[i];
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
    });
});
```

Hope this solution can help you.

Comment: No, it's not necessary to do that. AJAX requests can return HTML. Returning JSON is just one option, it's not mandatory. Try to suggest a fix to the actual problem, instead of an unnecessary re-write.